# Qual a melhor tradução para "left" neste contexto?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Gostaria de saber a tradução para a palavra *left* no trecho:

> I live in New Orleans, and the neighborhood where I live is very devastated. There are no schools **left**. To go to school I have to walk about 2 miles.

Traduzir *left* como *esquerda* fica sem sentido.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser mais sobre o significado de uma expressão inglesa do que propriamente como expressar dada ideia em português. Da próxima, devias tentar antes o site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traduzir *left* por esquerda nesse trecho ficaria mesmo sem sentido. Nesse trecho *left* é o particípio passado do verbo *leave*; vê a [aceção 7 do Oxford Learner's Dictionary:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/leave_1)

> **be left** [transitive] to remain to be used, sold, etc. [restar para ser usado, vendido, etc.]

Não podemos traduzir *left* neste sentido isoladamente; uma boa tradução de *there are no schools left* é *já não há escolas* ou, só em português brasileiro, *não há mais escolas*. Tal como *left*, *já* e, no Brasil, *mais* indicam que houve escolas no passado, mas agora não há.

Outra possibilidade, sugerida nos comentários abaixo, é *não resta escola nenhuma*. Está absolutamente correto, mas no contexto original não me soa tão idiomático como as alternativas acima. Não consigo explicar porquê. Poderá ser uma idiossincrasia minha, até porque *das quatro escolas que aqui existiam não resta nenhuma* já me soa bastante bem.

Comment: ou _(já) não resta escola nenhuma_

Comment: "já não há escolas"  fica muito bem.  @Artefacto eu diria "já não resta nenhuma escola" ou "já não resta escola alguma".   Mas ouve-se igualmente "(já) não resta escola nenhuma" por estas bandas.

Comment: @Centaurus Folgo em saber. Eu não tinha a certeza se *já não há*... soaria bem no Brasil. Um dos meu memoráveis desentendimentos com brasileiros foi na universidade, quando eu ia tirar fotocópias para a turma toda, e um brasileiro me disse «não quero mais», e eu, «mas eu ainda não te dei nenhumas», e ele então clarificou, «já não quero». Como soaria *não há mais escolas*? Não incluí com receio de cometer alguma argolada.

Comment: "não há mais escolas" soa perfeitamente bem e, sem contexto, entendo como "já não há escolas".   Em determinado contexto ("Em Lisboa não há mais escolas do que no Porto")  seria certamente entendido de outra forma.  Em tempo, "nenhumas" foi um "typo" ?  Ao contrário de "algumas", nunca ouvi "nenhuma" no plural.

Comment: @Centaurus Sem contexto, «não há mais escolas» significa que já viste/enumeraste todas. Quando muito talvez «não mais há escolas» (soa ainda estranho); por aqui «não mais» significa geralmente «nunca mais»: «mudou-se para o Rio de Janeiro, onde começou a gravar, e até hoje não mais parou».

Comment: @Artefacto  Posso entender  «não há mais escolas» como "já vi/enumerei todas.", mas há que haver um contexto específico, como por exemplo: a) "Qual a próxima escola da lista?"     b) "Já não há mais escolas na lista.  Passemos agora para os hospitais."

Comment: @Centaurus Parece que o verbo *quedar* [não funciona para isso](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/quedar-vs-ficar.2513923/) em português, certo?

Comment: @tchrist  Em pt-BR "quedar" não é um verbo que faça parte da língua falada da maioria dos brasileiros.  Talvez tenha sido usado em alguma época mas atualmente fica restrito aos grandes literatos, "gente culta".  Seu significado "ficar" é muito pouco usado no sentido físico e não seria usado no sentido de "few schools left", mas sim em ficou triste, com medo, arrependida, etc.  Em [Geni e o Zepelin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWHH4MlyXQQ) uma balada de autoria de Chico Buarque de Holanda, esse verbo tão raro surge na frase "a cidade apavorada, se quedou paralisada"